# How to import a local SVG file in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, svg, webpack

I am trying to import a local SVG file in React but I keep coming across this error:
[image]

My code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "./images/logo.svg";

const MainImage = styled.div`
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #026857;
`;

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <MainImage>
        <Logo />
      </MainImage>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I have tried many solutions offered by others such as importing default as Logo, creating an image prop to contain the local svg (`<img src={'./images/logo.svg'}/>` ) but none have given me any success so far. I believe I may have to add something to my Webpack config file but I'm not sure what it is and where I should put it, as the config file is nearly 800 lines of code.

Also, I am using SVG files from https://undraw.co/ if the information helps, it seems their illustrations have many  tags in them which I have not seen in simple SVG icons.

```
<svg
      id="f6dc6f51-58d1-4328-a543-5a2c5176acea"
      dataName="Layer 1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="922.18516"
      height="747.35665"
      viewBox="0 0 922.18516 747.35665"
    >
      <path
        d="M420.91148,313.56734c-2.67984,100.75634,131.62869,203.61052,299.27661,203.61052S1154.817,318.5411,1028.01831,313.56734c-244.32514-9.5838-328.052-110.77046-303.55341-182.5C768.33985,2.60566,426.18809,115.17786,420.91148,313.56734Z"
        transform="translate(-138.90742 -76.32167)"
        fill="#3f3d56"
      />
      <polygon
        points="505.004 157.445 502.96 156.144 504.261 154.1 503.703 153.746 502.403 155.79 500.359 154.489 500.004 155.046 502.048 156.347 500.747 158.391 501.305 158.746 502.605 156.702 504.649 158.002 505.004 157.445"
        fill="#fcce33"
      />
      <polygon
        points="657.004 305.445 654.96 304.144 656.261 302.1 655.703 301.746 654.403 303.79 652.359 302.489 652.004 303.046 654.048 304.347 652.747 306.391 653.305 306.746 654.605 304.702 656.649 306.002 657.004 305.445"
        fill="#fcce33"
      />
...
```

Comment: Have you tried this? <İmg src={require('./images/logo.svg')} />

Comment: Yes. It gives me the same error but with a different message, "Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you are using Webpack 5, you need to configure your webpack [loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/) to something like this using [asset modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/):

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```

if you are using webpack 4, you can use [file-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) instead of `asset/resource`:

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```

then you can import your svg file like this:

```
import Logo from "./images/logo.svg";

//...

return <img src={Logo} />
```

Comment: I'm using Webpack 4 so I installed the file-loader and placed the SVG rules inside the existing module in my webpack config file, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: its hard to tell what the issue can be without seeing the webpack config file, but it should be able to pick up svg files. did you update your import statement to correctly reference the svg? `import Logo from "./images/logo.svg";` and reference the svg correctly? `<img src={Logo} />`?

Answer (score 2):

I usually always convert each SVG into its own component like so

```
import * as React from "react";

const ArrowDownSVG = (props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="24"
    height="24"
    strokeWidth={2}
    stroke="currentColor"
    fill="none"
    strokeLinecap="round"
    strokeLinejoin="round"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    {...props}
  >
    <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
    <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6" />
  </svg>
);

export default ArrowDownSVG;
```

Has worked for me in the past year or so
By leaving out the type for the props, you can use this in plain JS as well

Comment: Is the 'type' annotation only for TypeScript? I am not using TypeScript so it prompts an error when I add the props argument

Comment: yes, like i said you can leave out the ": React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>" part. In this case you can still pass any properties that an svg element has, while you also have a component that you can use